# Websocket reconexión

Tags: python, docker, websocket

me encuentro con el siguiente problema, tengo un bot que consiste en una conexión websocket a un nodo *Alchemy*, para obtener en tiempo real datos sobre transacciones en la blockchain de Ethereum. En lenguaje *Python*, el bot se encuentra *dockerizado* y corriendo en una instancia de *EC2* en *AWS*. El problema en si es que aparentemente no se reconecta, o bien el contenedor se detiene al momento de restablecer la conexión. Soy nuevo y no estoy del todo seguro si estoy haciendo bien la conexión websocket o si el error pasa por alguna configuración extra en *Docker*. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

A continuación dejo el código en cuestión y el código de error al momento de detenerse. Gracias.

```
websocket.enableTrace(True)
counter = 0

class ApiConection:
    """Connection to Alchemy node through 'AWS Secret Manager', 
    for greater security in API_KEY management"""
    
    logging.basicConfig(filename='api_loggs.log', format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
    secret = api_secret.get_secret()
    API_ALCHEMY = "wss://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/" + str(secret)

    def on_open(ws):
        print('Opened Connection')
        try:
            update_cloudwatch('< Opened Connection >')
        except Exception:
            print("Error in cloudwatch logs.. 'on_open'..")

        ws.send(json.dumps({
            "jsonrpc":"2.0",
            "id": 1, 
            "method": "eth_subscribe", 
            "params": 
                ["alchemy_filteredNewFullPendingTransactions", 
                {"address": "0x3819f64f282bf135d62168C1e513280dAF905e06"}] 
        }))

    def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
        print('Closed Connection')
        try:
            update_cloudwatch('< Closed Connection >')
            if close_status_code or close_msg:
                update_cloudwatch("close status code: " + str(close_status_code))
                update_cloudwatch("close message: " + str(close_msg))

        except Exception:
            print("Error in cloudwatch logs.. 'on_close'..")

    def on_message(ws, message):
        """Receiver of transactions and their metrics, via a websocket connection, 
        filters out data and publishes them in a 'SNS AWS' topic"""
        global counter
        topic_arn = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:360729631529:AlchemyTx"
        sns_client = boto3.client("sns")
        data = json.loads(message)
        
        if counter < 100000:
            if 'id' in data.keys():
                print ("Mensaje filtrado.. " + str(data))
                try:
                    update_cloudwatch('Mensaje filtrado >> ' + str(data)) 
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Error in cloudwatch logs.. 'on_message - if'.." + str(e))            
            else:
                sns_client.publish(TopicArn= topic_arn, Message= json.dumps(data['params']['result']))
                counter += 1
                print ("Mensaje enviado a SNS.. " + str(data['params']['result']))
                try:
                    update_cloudwatch('Mensaje enviado a SNS>> ' + str(data['params']['result']))      
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Error in cloudwatch logs.. 'on_message - else'.." + str(e))
        else:
            print("Control cut off... 100k transactions were sent...")
            update_cloudwatch('< Control cut off... 100k transactions were sent >')
            
    def on_error(ws, err):
        print("Got a an error: ", str(err))
        try:
            update_cloudwatch('< Error Connection >')
            update_cloudwatch(str(err))
        except ParamValidationError:
            print("< ParamValidationError >")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error in cloudwatch logs.. 'on_error'.." + str(e))

    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(API_ALCHEMY, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message, on_error=on_error)
    connection_status = ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})
    if connection_status == False:
        update_cloudwatch("< Websocket connection stopped >")
```

Esto es lo que me arroja el log de *Cloudwatch* al momento de la detención:

```
close status code: 1012

close message: Service Restart

< Websocket connection stopped >
```